# Print list item that throws error in for loop, and continue with next list item

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm trying to add some clarity to which file in a long list is throwing an error. I've tried wrapping the `for` loop in `tryCatch()`, but I can't get the behavior I'm looking for. The result I'm going for is: if file `i` throws an error `sprintf("Error: %s has a formatting problem", i)`.

Below, we create a directory with three files, two of which should be read correctly into a list by the `for` loop, one which will throw an error because it's a `xlsx` file.

**Note that the below code will create and delete a directory and three files**

```
dir.create("Demo999")
setwd("Demo999")

write.csv(mtcars,"mtcars.csv")
xlsx::write.xlsx(mtcars,"mtcars.xlsx")
write.csv(mtcars,"mtcars2.csv")


files <- list.files()
data <- list()

for (i in files){
    f <- read.csv(i)
    data[[i]] <- f

}

# clean up generated files

setwd("..")
unlink("Demo999", recursive= TRUE, force= TRUE)
```

My desired output is:

"Error: mtcars.xlsx has a formatting problem."

This code does not run, but is a sample `tryCatch` block:

```
tryCatch({
  for (i in files){
    f <- read.csv(i)
    data[[i]] <- f
  }
}, error = function() sprintf("Error: %s has a formatting problem", i))
```

Comment: Btw, I really appreciate that you included clean-up code.

Comment: @Gregor My pleasure, happy to make life easier for anyone who's taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `tryCatch` *inside the loop*, not outside the loop. You don't want try the whole loop, and do something else if the loop fails; you want the loop to try each list element, and print an error if it fails. This way you can go back and re-attempt only the failed files. Try this:

```
for (i in files){
    tryCatch({
      f <- read.csv(i)
      data[[i]] <- f
      },
      error = function(e) print(sprintf("Error: %s has a formatting problem", i))
    )
}
# [1] "Error: mtcars.xlsx has a formatting problem"

names(data)
# [1] "mtcars.csv"  "mtcars2.csv"
```

Note that, in this nice example, you know what succeeded from the `names(data)`, so you can easily find `fails = setdiff(files, names(data))`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on why `tryCatch` goes inside the loop. That makes much more sense now.