# Read and Combine text files in R

Tags: r

I have gone through most posts regarding this but nothing solves my issue. So need a little help.

I have a bunch of text files in a folder which I want to read and combine them into one.

I do it two ways:

```
mafs = list.files("MAF//", pattern = "TCGA")
data = lapply(mafs, read.table, header = T, sep = "\t", quote = "")
```

I get the following error

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
```

`line 21 did not have 324 elements`

I check the 21st file

```
twenty1st = read.table(mafs[21], header = T, sep = "\t", quote = "")
```

`dim(twenty1st)
[1] 108 324`

Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Try `readLines` rather than `read.table`.  `read.table` (as its name suggests)  will assume a delimited table structure, whereas I guess you are actually reading in lines of plain text.

Comment: I think it's not that the 21st file does not have 324 elements but some file does not have 324 elements in the 21st row.

Comment: To help debug you could put in a print statement, something like `lapply(mafs, function(x) {print(paste("Reading file", x)); read.table(x, header = T, sep = "\t", quote = "")})`. Then you could see the name of the file that errors out and check the 21st line of that file.

Comment: You could also try other read functions. You might have more luck with `readr::read_tsv` or `data.table::fread` (or not, if your file is really malformed). They'll at least be faster.

Comment: Print statement was helpful. I know how which file didnt have the 324 elements. Let me try to remove that file and read all others

Comment: @Gregor there seem to be more than one file with the same issue. The print statement depends on being able to read the file, so it stops everytime it encounters a file with lines which does not have 324 elements (as Gautam said).  Is there anyone I could get the problem files without reading it??

Comment: Well, yes, the `print` statement is a way to debug because whatever last printed will be the file with the issue. The more complicated, but more robust way is to use `tryCatch` so that your loop completes and you can go see which files are missing. I answered a question [about doing that a week or so ago, see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48231556/903061)